# String to BSON conversion using MongoDB java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I am performing the *collection.find()* operation by using the *mongo-java-driver 3.4* and taking the input from the end user into a String variable.

The String variable would try to replicate the Bson query.

> String qur = " or(eq(\"columname1\", \"value1\"),eq(\"columname2\",\"value2\"))";

However the find operation takes a Bson argument shown below

> Bson query=  or(eq("columname1", "value1"),eq("columname2","value2"));

Facing a challenge while converting the String input to the Bson format. Is there any solution to convert the same or is there any other input that can be provide to perform the find() operation ?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "string"? Because taking input as "strings" is really quite common. ( There's this little thing called the web that's been around for a little bit ). You could mean a simple parameter or you could mean something like a string in JSON Format. But your question is really unclear as to what you actually mean.

Comment: Okay then the next logical thing to ask is "Why?" So why would you be presented with a "string" that looks like the construction of Java Code? Is this your own design? If so, then it's not a good one. Please take the time to explain what it is you actually want to achieve. Writing Java Code into strings is never going to be a good idea.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I am trying to write a Java method that would perform the find() operation and would take the multiple columname's and its corresponding values as arguments, to query the collection and hence adopted this approach. Is there any other possible way to achieve the same ? Thanks.

Comment: Is it feasible to use JSON string to construct the Bson query in the same format ?  
Bson query= or(eq("columname1", "value1"),eq("columname2","value2"))

Comment: Why do you need to send an argument as a query? Why can you not simply send the parameter values? Or even the property names and values to query against those properties? This is detail that really should be explained in the question itself. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit your question to explain your case rather than presupposing "what you think should happen".